# Error while configuring glibc: Need linker with .init_array/.fini_array support

Tags: linux, glibc, linux-from-scratch

I am new to linux or LFS. I am building LFS 7.3 on virtual machine. I use Ubuntu 12.10.

For unknown reason, I can't partition the hard drive using cfdisk, so I create partition while installing the OS. I change the $LFS to /home/lost+found (the new partition).
Other than that, I followed all the tutorial in the LFS book precisely and I have successfully installed until point 5.6 in the book.

Now I am stuck at installing the first Glibc-2.17.
I use the following command to configure:

```
../glibc-2.17/configure \
--prefix=/tools \
--host=$LFS_TGT \
--build=$(../glibc-2.17/scripts/config.guess) \
--disable-profile \
--enable-kernel=2.6.25 \
--with-headers=/tools/include \
libc_cv_forced_unwind=yes \
libc_cv_ctors_header=yes \
libc_cv_c_cleanup=yes
```

I've tried to install gawk, and the error message did change. But I still got the following error when configuring:

```
checking for .preinit_array/.init_array/.fini_array support... no
configure: error: Need linker with .init_array/.fini_array support.
user@user:/home/lost+found/glibc-build$
```

What is probably wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I forgot some special configuration for 64-bit host. I tried to install again using ubuntu 32-bit and everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

your probably trying to use bad Compiler flags -- over optimization or `-fPIC` or some kind of `SSP/` hardening . Try the default optimization flags and see if it compiles ok

```
echo $CFLAGS
echo $CXXFLAGS
echo $CPPFLAGS
```

and examine the configparm file in your `glibc` build folder for your specs